# Subtract Float Value Between ViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, calculator, subtraction

This is ViewControllerOne:

```
- (IBAction)total {

float a = ([textfield1.text floatValue]);
float b = ([textfield2.text floatValue]);
float c = ([textfield3.text floatValue]);
float d = ([textfield4.text floatValue]);
float e = ([textfield5.text floatValue]);
float f = a+b+c+d+e+([textfield6.text floatValue]);

total.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"$%.2f", f];
```

This is View ControllerTwo:

```
float g = ([textfield1.text floatValue]);
float h = ([textfield2.text floatValue]);
float i = ([textfield3.text floatValue]);
float j = ([textfield4.text floatValue]);
float k = ([textfield5.text floatValue]);
float l = a+b+c+d+e+([textfield6.text floatValue]);
totalTwo.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"$%.2f", l];
```

In ViewControllerThree, I want to subtract the sum from ViewControllerOne with the sum of ViewControllerTwo and display the answer in a label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the values of sum `total.text` & `totalTwo.text` in `appDelegate` like

In AppDelegate.h file

```
float totalOne, totalTwo;
@propery(nonatomic)float totalOne, totalTwo;
```

In AppDelgate.m file,

```
@synthesize totalOne, totalTwo;

- (IBAction)total 
{
   //Create the instance of appDelegate as
   AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   float a = ([textfield1.text floatValue]);
   float b = ([textfield2.text floatValue]);
   float c = ([textfield3.text floatValue]);
   float d = ([textfield4.text floatValue]);
   float e = ([textfield5.text floatValue]);
   float f = a+b+c+d+e+([textfield6.text floatValue]);
   app.totalOne = f;
   total.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"$%.2f", f];
}

//Create the instance of appDelegate as
AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
float g = ([textfield1.text floatValue]);
float h = ([textfield2.text floatValue]);
float i = ([textfield3.text floatValue]);
float j = ([textfield4.text floatValue]);
float k = ([textfield5.text floatValue]);
float l = a+b+c+d+e+([textfield6.text floatValue]);
app.totalTwo = l;
totalTwo.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"$%.2f", l];

-(IBAction)btnCalculate
{
    //Create the instance of appDelegate as
    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    totalthree = app.totalOne - app.totalTwo;
    lbl.text = [NSString StringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", totalThree];
}
```

Comment: How do I store the sums in the AppDelegate? As float totalOne and float totalTwo?

Comment: Thank you, this is helping me finish up. On last question, I want the 'totalthree = app.totalOne - app.totalTwo;' display on 'label3' with a -(IBAction)Calculate. How can I display this sum when the button is clicked?

I appreciate all your help